# How to design a sql database with a publish/draft table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema, publish

I'm wondering how to make a scheme of database of blog. Authors writes articles and they publish them on blog. This is pretty simple with the tables like

> Author, Article, Blog

But the article can also have a draft. Draft cannot be seen by the readers and when the article is published it can be seen by the readers of the blog. Published article can be unpublished and it becomes a draft.

How to connect the

> draft

and

> publish

tables with the Articles and Blog tables? Is it necessary? Or maybe just add some columns to the Article table? Like IsPublished or something?

Comment: Your answered yourself in the last comment. Also have a think about if there are any other states (In progress? Awaiting Approval?)

Comment: why there's a blog table? if you have several blogs, then the blog table is necessary... but if you only have one then, get rid of that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few ways to handle this. One is to have a `status` flag on your content, which is useful for simple sites. The other is to have a join table connecting content to where, how, and when it should be displayed.

For simple sites, you'd just add a `status` flag to your content tables.

```
create type statuses as enum ('published', 'draft');

create table posts (
    id serial,
    author integer references people(id),
    content text not null,
    ...whatever other data...
    status statuses default 'draft'
);
```

I've used a [PostgreSQL enumerated type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-enum.html) to reduce storage space (not so important), so typos will be caught (important), and so there's a place to see what all the possible statuses are rather than their being added willy nilly (also important).

Then you can just select all posts which are published.

```
select *
from posts
where author = ? and
      status = 'published'
```

This is very simple, but the display and content are wielded together. And if you forget to check the `status` flag you'll show draft posts.

---

A variation on the `status` flag is to have a "publish at" date. Before this time it won't be displayed. After this time it will.

```
create table posts (
    id serial,
    author integer references people(id),
    content text not null,
    ...whatever other data...
    publish_at datetime default '9999-12-31'
);
```

Then you can check whether it should be displayed or not by seeing if `publish_at` is less than the current datetime.

```
select *
from posts
where author = ? and
      publish_at < current_timestamp
```

By defaulting to '9999-12-31' all posts are unpublished by default. This combines published/draft with the ability to automatically publish a post without having to run any extra code.

---

A more robust solution is to have a join table for what is to be published and where. Start with the same `posts` table, but no `status` column.

```
create table posts (
    id serial,
    author integer references people(id),
    content text not null,
    ...whatever other data...
);
```

Than have one for a person's blog.

```
create table blogs (
    id serial,
    curator integer references people(id)
);
```

Then create a join table connecting posts with a blog posts.

```
create table blog_posts (
    blog integer references blogs(id),
    post integer references posts(id),
    posted datetime not null default current_timestamp
);
```

Now when something is "published" it's inserted into `blog_posts`. There's no status flag. If you want to see a user's blog posts...

```
select *
from blog_posts
join blogs on blogs.id = blog_posts.blog
where blogs.curator = ?
order by posted desc;
```

The advantage here is one post can appear in multiple locations by adding more join tables or more fields to the blog_posts table. And there's no `status` field to remember to include in every statement. Either it's in the join table or it isn't.

`blog_posts` can also feature a `publish_at` field.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize it using this:

[image]

On "authors" table:

> basically all the information about the authors

On "articles" table:

> each article will have one author (generally... hmmmm but it can have more than one possibly but this will do). so the foreign key authors_id.

For the Published and Draft:

> "published" and "draft" are in the status field. In this case is enum('published', 'draft'). On your isPublished? I don't have anything against db designs with boolean values (ie yes/no, true/false) but it would be clearer if you have it as an enum. Probably later on you'll be adding there another status and your isPublished is not relevant anymore. A case could be: you'll need a status later on that says: "scheduled publish" or say "scheduled unpublish" or any other status.

With regards to the "blog" table:

> You don't necessarily need that if you have only one blog. But if you have several blogs, then you'd need that table.

as for the sql on the above:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `authors` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `status` ENUM('active', 'inactive') NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
  `content` TEXT NULL,
  `status` ENUM('published', 'draft') NULL,
  `datetime` INT NULL,
  `authors_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_articles_authors_idx` (`authors_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_articles_authors`
    FOREIGN KEY (`authors_id`)
    REFERENCES `authors` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
```